# How to retrieve posts that have thumbnail set?

Tags: php, wordpress

Anyone can help me with this one?

I've set my posts to have thumbnails. Is there any way to retrieve only posts with thumbnails?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you set your posts to have thumbnails exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your posts to have thumbnails the standard way, then you can always check if a post has a thumbnail using the [has_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) function. I'm not sure there's any way to ask WP_Query for posts with thumbnails, but I'm sure you can do it with a direct SQL query to $wpdb.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your wordpress loop just add this wrapper.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
{
    // run code for post
}
```

So your full code would most likely look something like this.

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while ( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
        {
            // output html code for the post here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`$only_thumbs = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_query' => array(array(
    'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    )),
));`
```